# Taxonomy slug by term ID

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, terms

I'm trying to modify wp_nav_menu to display term thumbnails. To get those thumbnails I need term ID and taxonomy slug: `$thumbnailimg = get_the_term_thumbnail($term_id, '$taxonomy', 'medium');`

I managed to get term ID for it with: `$term_id = (int)$item->object_id;`

But now I need to check if that object is a term AND what custom taxonomy that term belongs to (I have 2 of them).

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a menu object `$item`:

- `$item->object` stores the object the menu item refers to, e.g. 'post', 'page', 'my-cpt', or 'my-taxonomy' (the post type name, or the taxonomy name)
- `$item->type` stores what 'type' of object is it, either: 'post_type' or 'taxonomy'.

For custom links, these are both custom

Answer (score 0):

See if these functions will work for what you are trying to do:

- [term_exists](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)
- [get_taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies)